# How to make Service that is unremovable even if killed by the system?

Tags: android, service

I am creating a Blue light filter app. So that, I want to display the view over all the apps. I did it by the following Service,

```
public class OverlayService extends Service {
    public OverlayService() {}
    View mView;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        WindowManager.LayoutParams params;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 26)
            params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE
                            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN, 
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        else
            params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE
                            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP;
        params.setTitle("Load Average");
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        mView = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.overlay, null);
        wm.addView(mView, params);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mView != null) {
            ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).removeView(mView);
        }

    }
}
```

It works fine. But there is only one problem that

> "if I remove app from recents, It stops service then automatically
>   starts the service after few seconds"
>
> Why the service is stopped and restarted? How to avoid this?

I tried overriding **onStartCommand() and used START_STICKY** . But no use.

Help me. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: you can stop the service in `onDestroy()`

Comment: @Sniffer I want the service should be stopped only when user turns off it. But in my case the service is stopped when app is removed from recents.

Comment: then stop the service when user turn off the switch `Intent lintent = new Intent(context, ServiceName.class);
context.stopService(lintent);`

Comment: @Sniffer I edited my question. What I want is "service should continue running even if i remove my app from recents". But what happened is, "service is stopped and restarted after some seconds"

Comment: Did you mean, you want don't killable service even user try to remove your app from task manager

Comment: @Sniffer yes :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180918/discussion-between-sniffer-and-jyoti-jk).

Answer (score 1):

First Create **BroadcastReceiver**

```
public class Restarter extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i("Broadcast Listened", "Service tried to stop");
    Toast.makeText(context, "Service restarted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context, YourService.class));
    } else {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, YourService.class));
    }
 } 
}
```

Add below code in your service

```
 @Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    stoptimertask();

    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
    broadcastIntent.setAction("restartservice");
    broadcastIntent.setClass(this, Restarter.class);
    this.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
}



private Timer timer;
private TimerTask timerTask;
public void startTimer() {
    timer = new Timer();
    timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            Log.i("Count", "=========  "+ (counter++));
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 1000, 1000); //
}

public void stoptimertask() {
    if (timer != null) {
        timer.cancel();
        timer = null;
    }
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

In your MainActivity add below code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Intent mServiceIntent;
private YourService mYourService;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mYourService = new YourService();
    mServiceIntent = new Intent(this, mYourService.getClass());
    if (!isMyServiceRunning(mYourService.getClass())) {
        startService(mServiceIntent);
    }
}

private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            Log.i ("Service status", "Running");
            return true;
        }
    }
    Log.i ("Service status", "Not running");
    return false;
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    stopService(mServiceIntent);
    super.onDestroy();
}   }
```

In Manifest.XML

```
 <receiver
    android:name="Restarter"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="restartservice" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
add this method in service class

```
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent){
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
 }
```

Comment: Where should we use this?

Comment: if you are having Application class then you can do like this "service.stop()" in onDestroy method of application class

Comment: @JyotiJK  you can also try
this in your activity onDestroy "stopService(new Intent(this, Your_service.class));"

Answer (score 0):

the service must be restarted because android donot allow it. You can use [Foreground](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)) service to improve your app.