# How to run a service even when phone is idle?

Tags: android, database, service

I know that this question has been asked multiple times. And from other SO questions, this is what I tried. I am returning device location and phone state every 15 mins to SQLITE and sending it to server the next day. How to avoid service getting killed by Android when phone is idle? (Converting to System app is out of question.)

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.e("onCreate", "Service Method");

        mTelephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        if (mTimer != null) {// Cancel if already existed
            mTimer.cancel();
            mTimer = null;
        }
        mTimer = new Timer(); //recreate new
        mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new ConnectActivity(), 0, 900000); //Schedule task
    }
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
        // stopped, so return sticky.
        startServiceForeground(intent, flags, startId);
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    public int startServiceForeground(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, DeviceStatusService.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "channel_id")
                .setContentTitle("NOTIFICATION NAME")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.default)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .build();

        startForeground(300, notification);

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,this.getClass());
        startService(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.e("onDestroy", "Service Method");
        mTimer.cancel(); //For Cancel Timer
        mTimer.purge();
        mTimer = null;
        super.onDestroy();
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("RestartService");
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    }
```

Also, I have used this `manifest.xml`:

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".ServiceRestarterBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:label="RestartServiceWhenStopped">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="RestartService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

<service
        android:name=".DeviceStatusService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:stopWithTask="false"/>
```

**ServiceRestarterBroadcastReceiver.class**

```
public class ServiceRestarterBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    /*context.startService(new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), DeviceStatusService.class));*/
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context, DeviceStatusService.class));
            } else {
                context.startService(new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), DeviceStatusService.class));
            }
        }
    }, 60000);

    }
}
```

The problem that I face is if the screen is off and the device goes to idle state, somehow the service is either killed or does not return any value to the DB.

P.S: It worked fine when the device is in use. This problem persists especially when you do not use the device.

Comment: Look at [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52550113/5978440)

Comment: @HarishJose Exactly.. Now that's why I tried to run it also as foreground so that service keeps running. Yet somehow if it's idle for long time, my task does not happen..

Comment: @Sniffer bro.. have implemented that as well actually.. I will update my code.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should not use a Service for this purpose. You should use some sort of task shedulers. There are a lot of them - AlertManager, JobSheduler etc. And sometime it's really tricky to choose one. I recommended to start from this article: https://medium.com/mindorks/android-scheduling-background-services-a-developers-nightmare-c573807c2705

Comment: Hey thanks.. But I can't use schedulers as my minSDK is 19.. Now Android job doesn't work as I have to run this service every 15 mins.. I have problem only when phone goes to idle state. Don't know if Android is killing the service. But sometimes the foreground process is running yet the DB operation does not happen.. What do you think?

Comment: Have you read the article? :) GCM Network Manager, mentioned on it, can be used from Api 9. And why do you need to send the data every 15 minutes? Think, is it really necessary?

Comment: Nope. I don't need to send the data every 15 mins.. But I am retrieving data every 15 mins and writing it to sqlite.. Then I am sending the same next day.. Apparently I figured out now that my service is running yet, sqlite operation does not happen in the background for every 15 mins..

Comment: Ok. But why do you need to store data every 15 minutes? If your device is idle it means that it's location is not changing etc. See this: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/power/platform_mgmt

Comment: It's a client requirement and basically I am against these.. But if a user is travelling and not using his phone. The device is still idle right?

Comment: And for qsn why I need to store data, I basically need to know the user whereabouts and store it every 15 mins to monitor his working status..